# Is the files.get() method affected by the file size in Java?

Tags: java, filesystems

I want to check the log file information (modification time, file size) using Paths.get() to make sure that log files in was are stacking properly. However, the log file is over 5GB in size. Reading the entire file from was causes a huge I/O Cost, so I wonder if the log file size is affected when creating a File object with paths.get().

Answer (score 3):

Seems like something that you could have trivially tested.

The answer is no. The size of the file has absolutely no bearing whatsoever on this; `Paths.get("/floobargle/gobbledygook/nonexistentfile")` is in fact legal, because no disk access of any sort occurs.

You won't even touch the disk until you run some method in `Files`.

You're again in luck, though: All the various Files.x methods that clearly do not need to know about the file contents (such as: Who owns this file, what is the last modified time of this file, what is the parent dir of this file, is this file actually a link, etc), aren't affected by it either.